# python2.7 :count values in key/value pair

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a list of key/value pairs

I'd like to count unique values in pairs

example of list

```
[(12, 0), (10, 1), (11, 777), (11, 0) ,(10, 1)]
```

result something like :

```
[(12, 0, 1), (10, 1 , 2), (11, 777, 1), (11, 0, 1)]
```

I tried map operations , but didn't succeed
Thanks !

Comment: What are the pairs? When is a value unique?

Comment: You could use dict with pairs in first list as keys.

Comment: I'd like construct a method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>>
>>> lst = [(12, 0), (10, 1), (11, 777), (11, 0) ,(10, 1)]
>>> [key + (cnt,) for key, cnt in Counter(lst).items()]
[(11, 0, 1), (11, 777, 1), (10, 1, 2), (12, 0, 1)]
```

Comment: Thanks ! I'm trying to construct a function :       from collections import Counter
def count_list([lst]):    
    [key + (cnt,) for key, cnt in Counter(lst).items()]

Comment: @Toren, `def method(lst): return [key + (cnt,) for key, cnt in Counter(lst).items()]`

Comment: What is import scope ? Can I import somewhere before the method ?

Comment: @Toren, Yes before the method. `import` statement in the beginning of the module (file) is recommended.

Answer (score 2):

Using `collections.Counter`:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> a =[(12, 0), (10, 1), (11, 777), (11, 0) ,(10, 1)] 

>>> [(*i,j) for (i,j) in Counter(a).items()]
# [(11, 0, 1), (11, 777, 1), (10, 1, 2), (12, 0, 1)]

>>> [i for i in Counter(a).items()]
# [((11, 0), 1), ((11, 777), 1), ((10, 1), 2), ((12, 0), 1)]
```

Comment: [`(*i, j)` syntax is available in Python 3.5+](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.5.html#whatsnew-pep-448). The question is tagged `python-2.7`

Answer (score 1):

Would something like this work for you?

```
your_list = [(12, 0), (10, 1), (11, 777), (11, 0) ,(10, 1)]
result = [(a,b,your_list.count((a,b))) for (a,b) in your_list]
# [(12, 0, 1), (10, 1, 2), (11, 777, 1), (11, 0, 1), (10, 1, 2)]
```

If you want each entry to appear only once you could do

```
set(result)
# set([(12, 0, 1), (11, 0, 1), (11, 777, 1), (10, 1, 2)])
```

Comment: This can be combined into: `result = [(a,b,l.count((a,b))) for (a,b) in set(l)]`

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it with built-in `map` method, this way:

```
>>> l = [(12, 0), (10, 1), (11, 777), (11, 0) ,(10, 1)]
>>> result = []
>>> map(lambda s: result.append((s[0],s[1],l.count(s))), set(l)) 
[None, None, None, None]
>>> result
[(11, 0, 1), (11, 777, 1), (10, 1, 2), (12, 0, 1)]
```